Questions regarding robot localization
By the way, I already made a custom robot with IMU, GPS, and odometry (wheel encoders) and added noise to these sensors too. I made a custom robot from a nav2 tutorial. Additionally, I also used EKF from robot_localization packages and add noise to IMU, GPS, and odometry. Through my checking simulation, it seems everything is okay since my simulation could publish information regarding pose of a custom robot for IMU, GPS, and odometry by moving a robot with a teleop keyboard, however I am still hesitant to call everything correct since I am a beginner for ROS2. So, could I ask your suggestions and your general feedback regarding my code? (main task)
Additionally, I also want to generate picture exactly like below picture (secondary task)

Here, my link for code https://github.com/jsuria22/rob_localization
colcon build

source install/setup.bash

ros2 launch sam_bot_description display.launch.py

ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard --ros-args -r cmd_vel:=/demo/cmd_vel

